# How to know whether a terminal runs on a virtual machine or Docker?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, terminal, docker

How to know whether a terminal runs on a virtual machine or a container like Docker? Curious to find it.

Comment: Where? When? How? What is the circumstance you are trying to understand this within?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to try finding information related to docker.

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope" | head -n 1 | sed "s/docker-\(.*\).scope/\\1/"
```

The above will return an ID if inside a docker container. More information about this command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/how-can-i-get-docker-linux-container-information-from-within-the-container-itsel)

If it fails probably you're not inside a docker container.